# How to set value of NSString into NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I want to know how to set a value of NSString into NSArray

```
NSString *holdTheNumberToUpload;
NSArray *resultFetch;

self.resultFetch.count = holdTheNumberToUpload
```

I used this way:

```
if (!self.resultFetch.count) {


    [self.defaults setObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)self.resultFetch.count] forKey:@"holdTheNumberToUpload"];
}
```

Comment: You can [`add`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1411274-addobject?changes=_6&language=objc) an object to (the end of) an array or [`insert`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1416682-insertobject?changes=_6&language=objc) an object at a specific index however you need an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Thank you, can you be more specific? do you have an example?

Comment: Please click on `add` and `insert` in my first comment. It leads to the documentation.

Comment: Your question is confusing. `setObject:forKey:` is related to `NSMutableDictionary` and the error says that all values in a dictionary must be objects (you have to create an NSNumber object from the integer `@(self.resultFetch.count)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an NSMutableArray instead of a NSArray. It would look like this:

```
NSString *holdTheNumberToUpload = @"Whatever";
NSMutableArray *resultFetch = [NSMutableArray array];
[resultFetch addObject:holdTheNumberToUpload];
```

Also, I'm not sure how you're using `resultFetch.count`. This value is an NSUInteger, so your check `if (!resultFetch.count)` will never be work because it will always be a non-negative number.

Answer (score 0):

The words you use in your question don't seem to have anything to do with the screen shot. The problem with the code in the screen shot is the expression

```
[(unsigned long)self.resultFetch.count]
```

What is that supposed to be? If it's supposed to a number, remove the square brackets. If it's supposed to be an array, put `@` in front of it:

```
@[(unsigned long)self.resultFetch.count]
```

But that won't compile either, because `(unsigned long)self.resultFetch.count` is not an *object*. Therefore it cannot be an element of an array, nor can it be the parameter of `setObject`. Either way, you need to wrap it in an NSNumber, which *is* an object. Again, you can do this with `@`:

```
@self.resultFetch.count
```

or, if you really insist on the cast to `unsigned long`,

```
@((unsigned long)self.resultFetch.count)
```

So, depending what on earth your code is supposed to mean, you might end up with something like (you want a number?):

```
@self.resultFetch.count
```

or something like (you want an array containing a number?):

```
@[@self.resultFetch.count]
```